# npx expo install results in TypeScript errors

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I recently setup a new React Native project using expo following the docs [here](https://docs.expo.dev/get-started/create-a-project/#initialize-a-new-project). I am following subsequent [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation)  to do things such as implement a NavigationContainer. In the instructions it says "If you have an Expo managed project, install the dependencies with Expo:" then provides a command such as `npx expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context`. When I run this command, I get a bunch of TypeScript errors such as:

```
node_modules/@types/node/buffer.d.ts:2344:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'Blob' must be of type '{ new (blobParts?: (string | Blob)[] | undefined, options?: BlobOptions | undefined): Blob; prototype: Blob; }', but here has type 'typeof Blob'.

2344         var Blob: typeof globalThis extends {
                 ~~~~
  node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:78:13
    78 declare var Blob: {
                   ~~~~
    'Blob' was also declared here.
node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts:47:11 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'AbortController'.
47 interface AbortController {
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:515:15
    515 declare class AbortController {
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'AbortController' was also declared here.
```

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "lint": "gts lint",
    "clean": "gts clean",
    "compile": "tsc",
    "fix": "gts fix",
    "prepare": "npm.cmd run compile",
    "pretest": "npm.cmd run compile",
    "posttest": "npm.cmd run lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/node": "20.8.2",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "gts": "^5.2.0",
    "typescript": "~5.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**UDATED with tsconfig.json**
My `tsconfig.json` file is:

```
{
  "extends": "./node_modules/gts/tsconfig-google.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "build",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "test/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

When I run the `npx expo install` command I expect it to successfully install the packages, but it fails with these errors. I am able to work around it by just using plain `npm install` instead, but I am worried my "Expo managed" application is not setup properly.

I still don't fully understand what Expo is giving me outside of "barebones React Native," but that is likely out of scope of this question and can be answered by me doing more research.

Comment: A definitive answer probably will require you to include your TS config but declarations in the types package for node runtime are overlapping with and disagreeing with declarations in the react native package.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I updated the post with my ```tsconfig.json``` contents.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's a conflict in typings. You could remove `"@types/node": "20.8.2"` in `devDependencies`. Then delete `node_modules` and install dependencies from scratch.

Comment: This did not work for me